# Form attribute accept encoding has no effect in MS Edge

Tags: php, html, forms, authentication

I have a Login-Form in HTML/PHP which uses the `accept-charset` attribute in the `<form>`-tag, because there were problems with passwords which use German "**Umlaute**" and other special-chars.

In Firefox and Chrome everything works as expected. Only MS Edge refuses the password as wrong.

So the PHP-Loginscript gets wrong data from Edge - I think because the `accept-charset` is ignored.

What can I do, to solve this problem? How can I tell MS Edge to use `accept-charset="ISO-8859-15"`?

Comment: Are any passwords refused? Have you checked what you the PHP script receives? That would be helpful.

Comment: So, i checked it. I logged it in a MySQL-Table with Collation utf-8 general.

PW is Mühsamm99/

If i try to login with Edge it logged "Mühsamm99/" in the Database - and PW is refused

If I try it with Chrome it logged "M" in the Database - and PW is accepted

Answer (score 0):

Now, the solution:

IE and Edge obviously ignore the accept-charset attribute.

I solved my problem - yes, my english is also a problem ;) - with the following JavaScript:

```
<form ... accept-charset="ISO-8859-1" onsubmit="document.charset = 'ISO-8859-1'">
```

That's ok, because what's after login also requieres JavaScript to be enabled